# Create poster with overlay and scale

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm working on creating a thumbnail from a video and adding an overlay. The following is working great; it outputs a JPG with the PNG overlay.

```
ffmpeg -ss 15 -i input.mp4 -i play-button.png \
-filter_complex overlay='(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2' \
-vframes 1 poster.jpg
```

However, I'd like to scale the thumbnail down, so I tried adding `scale='min(640\, iw):-1'`

```
ffmpeg -ss 15 -i input.mp4 -i play-button.png \ 
-filter_complex overlay='(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2' \
-vframes 1 scale='min(640\, iw):-1' poster.jpg
```

But when doing that I receive errors

```
Unable to find a suitable output format for 
'scale=min(640\, iw):-1' scale=min(640\, iw):-1: Invalid argument
```

I've tried `qscale` and adding `image2`,  and playing around with a lot of different options but just can't find the one that works.

#### Edit

This is what I was previously using to create my poster image, I just needed to add an overlay. But when trying to combine the two it all fell apart.

```
ffmpeg -ss 15 -i input.mp4 -f image2 -vf scale='min(640\, iw):-1' \
vframes 1 poster.jpg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to formulate all filters within a single graph, so

```
ffmpeg -ss 15 -i input.mp4 -i play-button.png \
  -filter_complex overlay='(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2',scale='min(640\, iw):-1 \
  -vframes 1 poster.jpg
```